# How to make an animation special effect in an android game?

Tags: java, android, animation, opengl-es, gif

I am attempting to make a 2D android game which is being coded in java and I have a question. How would one display an electricity zap animation as if it was sparking between 2 Tesla Coils? I have explored using a GIF but when the screen is panned the GIF animation pauses until released.

I have considered Open GL but that looks daunting at this stage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[LibGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) is a great framework for android game development, take a look at this particle editor [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ParticleEditor). It provides a nice abstraction over OpenGL, but if you want, there is no problem accessing OpenGL in raw form.